# Shared ClearCase DO availability for winkin

Tags: clearcase

How soon after creating a shared DO in one view is it available for winkin in another view? In other words, if I have 'view_a' that is creating shared DOs, are there any process handles, etc that have to be closed first, before that DO is made available to be winked-in to 'view_b'? (assuming both cspecs and build rules are setup properly such that winkins are expected). I have a scenario where a DO is created, but not winked-in. If I wait long enough though, it does get winked in.

Comment: What are DO:s and what version of clearcase are you using?

Comment: DOs are "derived objects" - essentially the build byproducts. We are using CC 7.1.2.4, in a Linux Cent)S 6.x environment.

Comment: The reason I ask is so that you can add that information to the text. So people searching for your question might find it. Wish you well on Stackoverflow. And welcome!

Comment: OK yes, excellent point! I have a bad habit of over-abbreviating sometimes ... it annoys my co-workers as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the "[Working with DOs and configuration records](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_build_windows.doc/working_with_dos_and_configuration_records.htm)", there shouldn't be any significant delay.
You could have permission issue though. You can try to [winkin the DO manually](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_build_windows.doc/working_with_dos_and_configuration_records.htm) to see if the issue persists, or to better detect the nature of said issue.

Comment: The thing is - the same userID that fails to wink-in initially, is able to do so after waiting x-amount of time, without any changes to the ENV (permissions, etc). The challenge now is to define that window, and see if it's related to NetApp storage or nfs latency, for example, or some other factor that may influence the winkin operation or DO shopping. Enabling CCASE_VERBOSITY will allow us to gather some additional data as well.

Comment: @VonC How come you know everything about CC! :D